# I have n-dimensional latent representational data, with a y logit label: How do I find peaks in the data using the label?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, clustering, latent-variable

I essentially need a "find peaks" algorithm for when the input data is n-dimensional.

Specifically, in the latent space of my neural network I have have collected all the training data representations and their corresponding output logit value.

I want to find the "peaks" in the logit values, so I can cluster the data around these peaks. So, for example, if I have 2 peaks in the logit values, I want two centroid values for these peaks in the n-dim data.

It seems "find peaks" algorithms like the one in scipy only work for 1d input data assumed to be in a sequence. Is there any way to do this in n-dim data? Thank you

Comment: in other words, you want to take the latent n-dims values of each class and find the modes of these only latents?